# Why is Chrome's shape-outside inspector offset?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-shapes, inspector

I've been learning about the CSS shape-outside property today and I think I've got the hang of it.

However, when I'm inspecting the polygon shape in chrome it's offset slightly downwards and rightwards (pictured).

Why is this? Can I change it? And if so, how?

[image]

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

img {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 60% 0%, 65% 10%, 60% 25%, 95% 48%, 95% 50%, 65% 55%, 60% 80%, 68% 95%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="title">HELLO</h1>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua....(etc.)</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua....(etc.)</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua....(etc.)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will update my question with the code but I don't think it's a coding problem. As you can see, the text flows around the actual image perfectly, rather than around the purple shaded polygon. It seems to be something weird happening as part of Chrome's developer tools. I've replicated the same problem while using standard shapes like circle() too. Each time the purple shaded area of the shape is offset from the area of effect.

Comment: Ok. I've updated my question with the code - although of course I can't replicate the image and all associated polygon coordinates in a snippet.

Comment: updated your question with an example image - looks fine on my chrome. Which version / OS do you use?

Comment: How weird! Chrome assures me I'm using the latest version (Version 67.0.3396.99) and I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Me too and its working fine. Any plugins/extensions?

Comment: Nothing. I mean it's not that big a deal really. Just mildly annoying when I'm trying to see where the path is and I've got this great purple block in my way. But never mind. Thanks for try to help.

Comment: Seems to work fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBMwmv (added the clip-path to the demo to see it better)